# Calling a variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I have a create person button, and some radio buttons where I can assign a gender to the person. Ie: Male or Female.

```
$('#BtnCreatePerson').click(function(e)
{   
var sPersonGender = $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val();
}
```

What do I do if I need to call the variable in another function in an external js file and place it in an if statement. Like

```
if (gender == Male && gender == Female)
{
   do something
}
```

**UPDATE:** I still can't get it to work. I've created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/qY9Dw/). It's a bit messy, i know.

Comment: You would set a variable non local to the function, which exists in a scope accessible to both the handler and the code in the if statement.

Comment: How can `gender` be equal to both `Male` and `Female`?

Comment: pass gender in the call as a function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would store the value outside of the function, possibly as a property of an object you have created, or the `window` object.

```
Person = {};

$('#BtnCreatePerson').click(function(e) {   
   Person.gender = $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val();
});
```

And in your other file:

```
if (Person) {
   if (Person.gender === "Male") {
       // some code...
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Not?

```
if ($("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val()== Male && 
$("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val()== Female)
{
   do something
}
```

Also I think that's an OR, since they can't be both male AND female :p